# MySQL: Adding Foreign Key with field value to be constant

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I have two tables as below,

CustAddr {custid, addrtype, address} 
& OrderDetails {orderid, custid,.....,delivery-address}

I want to add FK on OrderDetails such that (custid, delivery-address) always refer to (custid, 'CURRENT', address) in CustAddr table. The idea is, I can not add delivery-address to Order-Details if address is not current.

My question,
1. Is it possible to do this in MysQL INNODb?
2. If not, what are the alternatives?

Thanks...

PS: I am giving above tables as example, my tables are completely different. But this analogy is easy to understand. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can't make a foreign key constraint enforce that.

But you could use `BEFORE INSERT` and `BEFORE UPDATE` triggers to enforce the assignment of `CURRENT` to a given column, in this case, your foreign key column `addrtype` in `order_detail` table.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER order_detail_bi
BEFORE INSERT ON order_detail
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    NEW.addrtype = 'CURRENT';
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

You'd also need a corresponding `BEFORE UPDATE` triggger. The rest is handled by the foreign key definition:

```
ALTER TABLE order_detail ADD CONSTRAINT FK_order_detail_custaddr 
  FOREIGN KEY (custid,addrtype)
  REFERENCES custaddr (custid, addrtype)
```

**EDIT**

It is possible to define the foreign key constraint with

```
  ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

A `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger on `order_detail` would not be fired for rows affected by "cascade" update operation. (That's a strange quirk with MySQL. That does make it more complicated to write "audit" triggers that record updates and deletes caused by "cascade" operations.)

The `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger could just prevent changes to the value of the `attrtype` column, for example:

```
CREATE TRIGGER order_detail_bi
BEFORE INSERT ON order_detail
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    NEW.addrtype = OLD.addrtype;
END$$
```

Such that the only way to get a different value would either be through a "cascade" update, or by disabling the trigger before performing an UPDATE, and re-enabling the trigger.

Comment: Thanks..I was trying to avoid trigger if possible. Adding trigger has one downside imo, I can not use 'ON UPDATE CASCADE' feature of FK. With that, it was possible for me automatically update delivery address in all pending orders if customer changes his CURRENT address.

Comment: @aniket: Yes. Actually, you could get an `ON UPDATE CASCADE` to work, that could change the value of the `addrtype` column in the `order_detail` table to a value other than `CURRENT`. (In MySQL, triggers aren't fired for rows affected by "cascade" actions... but a subsequent `UPDATE` of a row would cause the trigger to fire. You could have the `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger do a check, **`IF NOT (NEW.addrtype <=> OLD.addrtype) THEN`**  bypassing the assignment of `CURRENT` to the column when the value isn't being changed. Or, just do a `SET NEW.addrtype = OLD.addrtype;` to prevent any change to it.

Answer (score 0):

I am new to MySql, but I ran into this same problem. To solve it, I used an ENUM field for the `addrtype` in the CustAddr table with one of the ENUM values being 'CURRENT', like this:

In CustAddr table:

```
addrtype ENUM ('CURRENT', <more strings . . . >) NOT NULL;
```

In the OrderDetails table, I have this restricted ENUM:

In OrderDetails table:

```
alwayscurrent ENUM ('CURRENT') NOT NULL;
```

In the foreign key, I'm planning to use the `alwayscurrent` field as the actual argument for the `addrtype` component. I'm just in the design phase, so I haven't yet tested this idea. I'll get to try it out next week when I have access to MySQL Workstation.